# Pass a literal tab from a Java command through a shell script to another bash command

Tags: bash

I have a Java application that calls a bash script that calls another shell command using `"$@"`. I need to pass through a literal tab character to the final command it calls. If I call the second command directly using `$'\t'` it works, but if I use `$'\t'` as one of the arguments in `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` it just passes it through as a string.

Comment: Please provide a specific example of the behavior you want, and the behavior you're getting. As it is, I don't understand why you would expect `"$@"` to pass through _only_ a tab character, rather than the entire set of arguments.

Comment: I don't expect it to only pass through the tab character. I want it to run and evaluate the $'\t' character exactly as does if I call it directly (which works), but when that argument is passed through using "$@" the receiving script no longer gets the argument as a tab literal.

Comment: Using `"$@"` **definitely** passes through tab literals unmolested. If you can provide a standalone reproducer demonstrating otherwise, I'd be most interested.

Comment: (part of the point of making appropriate use of StackOverflow's markdown syntax, by the way, is to make it clear when quotes are intended to be literally taken as code, as opposed to interpreted as division points between code and prose).

Comment: I think the issue may be that the first script is kicked off by a Java webserver using java.lang.Process

Comment: A java.lang.Process object created how, exactly?

Comment: ...I ask because if you're using the literal-array form of `Runtime.exec()`, you should be good to go; the string form, not so much.

Comment: https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/genie-server/src/main/java/com/netflix/genie/server/jobmanager/impl/HadoopJobManager.java
https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/genie-web/conf/system/apps/genie/bin/joblauncher.sh
executeHadoop

Comment: *shudder*. That's some astonishingly awful shell... but then, par for the course for Java developers.

Comment: ...anyhow -- that shell script is full of quoting bugs, so even if it were invoked with correctly split arguments, they wouldn't be _staying_ correctly split during its execution.

Comment: ...well, I say that, but its use of `"$@"` looks fine (though little else does).

Comment: The ProcessBuilder usage in the java code looks fine at first glance, though I'd need to do a more thorough audit to be completely certain. If you can, though, I'd start by using `sysdig 'evt.type=execve'` or `strace -e trace=process` to look at the literal argv arrays passed to each `execve()` call.

Comment: I'm certainly not above forking it and fixing it, I'm working on a test case with a java application calling a shell script calling echo

Comment: I'd suggest `printf '%q\n' "$@"` rather than `echo`; does a better job of displaying unprintable characters in an unambiguous manner.

Comment: The echo of $CMD "$@" in joblauncher.sh looks correct, but the command it's calling gets the value as a string instead of a tab. My simple echo script prints the tab.

Comment: Update your question with a pair of scripts that, used together, demonstrate the problem. `echo` really can't be trusted -- see again re: `printf '%q '`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a demonstrator showing correct behavior.

Comment: The odd part to me is the difference in behavior between the two. I think the issue is that when it's called from Java it is just a string, but when it's called from the shell it gets evaluated to a tab

Comment: Verified that the Java process is the root of the problem and updated the question.

Comment: There's an argument to be made that this is more a new question than a refinement, and should have been asked as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible issues:

- If you're passing the literal five-character string `$'\t'` in a ProcessBuilder array, it's not being passed to a shell at all, and so is never converted to a tab character.
- If you're passing the literal five-character string `$'\t'` in a shell invocation string (not an array) passed to ProcessBuilder, this is invoked with `/bin/sh`, not bash, so bash extensions such as `$''` are not available.

You need to pass a literal tab character, not a `$'\t'` sequence.

Comment: Any ideas on what I could pass in an http call that would be evaluated as a literal tab? Is there a similar sequence for /bin/sh?

Comment: @bridiver Just as a literal space is `%20` when urlescaped, a literal tab is `%09`. If you aren't meaning urlescaping, I don't know why you think you can't just pass the literal tab as, well, a literal tab, whether or not it's going over HTTP. After all, it's a low-ASCII character, and can go over any 7-bit-clean channel, and very little is not.

Comment: Yea, I guess for some reason I kept thinking I had to pass some kind of escape sequence. I'll try just sending the tab character and see if that makes it all the way through ok.

Comment: Looking back, the issue is that I was starting from a YAML configuration file, so I needed to use some kind of escape sequence to represent the tab

Comment: Why would that be? Literal tabs embedded in YAML strings should work fine -- albeit perhaps a little hard for readers to visually distinguish.

Comment: I don't believe you can use a tab as a value because a tab is considered whitespace in the YAML specification http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2775170

Comment: @bridiver, whitespace is only discarded outside of quoted strings; inside quoted strings, it's preserved.